# The package multiqc can not work and allways got SyntaxError: invalid syntax problem

Tags: python, package

I have got a very weird problem. I have installed the package `multiqc` by pip on **Python 3.7+**. The install succeeded I can find the multiqc on pip list. But I cant use the command `multiqc --help` or `multiqc -h` in cmd, I am using a windows computer by the way. Moreover, after go into the python I did import the package but the command multiqc . don't work and always tell me:

```
"SyntaxError: invalid syntax".
```

Do anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

```
 C:\Users\qwesx>python
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import multiqc
>>> multiqc .
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    multiqc .
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It looks like this.

Comment: Please show us how you import and what error message throws when working with it! Place the entire snippet here.

Comment: @SekarRamu I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiqc is not something you will be using inside python command prompt. You need python as a dependency to Multiqc.

Once you have installed it, you can run it in the command prompt directly pointing to the directory where you want your report to be generated.

You can go thru the official documentation of multiqc in

Github: https://github.com/ewels/MultiQC/blob/master/docs/usage.md
or in the official website https://multiqc.info/docs/

Please let me know in case of any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried "multiqc."  in command prompt, but it still does not work it says it is Not an internal or external command. Then I tried "python -m multiqc ." And it said  D:\Python37\python.exe: No module named multiqc.__main__; 'multiqc' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: I have tried it on my Linux system and it works now thank you.

Comment: Note that MultiQC does work on Windows, but the command is not as nice. You're looking for something like `python C:\\path\to\python\installation\multiqc`. MultiQC has automated tests that run on Windows, so you can see the commands here: https://github.com/ewels/MultiQC/blob/master/appveyor.yml